# Remove upload directory address from filepath

Tags: php, mysql

I add file input directory address from `kcfinder` to html input value like this:

```
/user/uploads/files/video/slider-bg2.jpg
```

Now I need to *only* file name with extension (like: slider-bg2.jpg) to insert to MySQL database. How can I remove or separate `/user/uploads/files/images/` from `slider-bg2.jpg`?

Comment: Please POST code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX("/user/uploads/files/video/slider-bg2.jpg","/",-1)
```

in mysql

SO

```
INSERT INTO table(columnname) values (SUBSTRING_INDEX("$yourFullFileNameWithDirectories","/",-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP’s [`pathinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get the `dirname` & `basename` from the full path provided & act on it accordingly.

```
$fullpath = '/user/uploads/files/video/slider-bg2.jpg';

echo '<pre>';
print_r(pathinfo($fullpath));
echo '</pre>';
```

The output would be:

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => /user/uploads/files/video
    [basename] => slider-bg2.jpg
    [extension] => jpg
    [filename] => slider-bg2
)
```

So you can then access the directory name by `$fullpath['dirname']` and the filename by `$fullpath['basename']`.